# Copy Excel data to exact PowerPoint slide cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, powerpoint

So I have a working Macro that copies Excel rows as pictures, and pastes each picture in a new PowerPoint slide.

So my job now is to to take individual data from an exact cell (for example A1, D1, H1, X1) and paste it in a predefined PowerPoint slide layout. So each cell goes to its corresponding place in the slide layout. I think only a bit of modifying is needed but I have absolutely no clue what to do. I'm really quite new with VBA so all help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time and have a great day! :)

```
Sub CopyRangeToPresentation()
'Variables
  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim SlideTitle As String
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim i As Integer
'Fider
  lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
'New presentation
Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
  Set PPpres = PP.Presentations.Add
  Set PP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
  PP.Visible = 1

For i = 1 To lRow
'New slide
      Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(i, ppLayoutBlank)
      PP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
      PPpres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
      PP.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
      PPslide.Select
'Copy
      Sheets("dataflows").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 24)).CopyPicture _
      Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
'Paste
      PPslide.Shapes.Paste.Select
      PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
      PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
'Title
Next i

'Memory
      PP.Activate
      Set PPslide = Nothing
      Set PPpres = Nothing
      Set PP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What issues are you getting with the code you have posted?  How does it differ from what you expect?  A minor change I would suggest is either capturing the `PPslide.Shapes.Paste` in an Object with (e.g. `Set PPShape = PPslide.Shapes.Paste`) or using it in a `With` (`With PPSlide.Shapes.Paste`), so that you can move it more easily

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom layout with text boxes in the positions you want the cells. The text inside the text boxes can be used to identify them (e.g. "mybox1"). You can google how to add a new slide from a custom layout. Then search through the shapes and paste the cells in the same locations. Something like this:

```
'Paste
  For Each PPshape In PPslide.Shapes
    If PPshape.HasTextFrame Then
        If PPshape.TextFrame.HasText Then
            If PPshape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "mybox1" Then
                PPslide.Shapes.Paste.Select
                PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = PPshape.Left
                PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = PPshape.Top
                PPshape.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next PPshape
```